# Unable to get the selection when using angular-winjs ListView

Tags: javascript, angularjs, listview, winjs

I'm using [angular-winjs](https://github.com/winjs/angular-winjs) to display a list. The HTML as well as the controller code is below. When I click the item, the **selection** is not set. As a result, the watch never gets called.

How can I get the selected item in the **selection** variable? My code looks similar to [this issue](https://github.com/winjs/angular-winjs/issues/1), but have the problem still. I'm using the latest WinJS.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="HomeTilesController">
        <div>Selected count: {{selection.length}}, indexes: {{selection}}</div>
        <win-list-view item-data-source="homeTiles" selection-mode="'single'" selection="selection">
            <win-item-template>
                <div class="tile">
                    <h5 class="win-h5">{{item.data.title}}</</h5>
                </div>
            </win-item-template>
            <win-grid-layout></win-grid-layout>
        </win-list-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

HomeTilesController:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['winjs'])
    .controller("HomeTilesController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.homeTiles = [
            { title: 'Agents' },
            { title: 'Center' },
            { title: '' },
            { title: '' },
            { title: '' },
            { title: '' }];

        $scope.selection = [1];

        $scope.$watch('selection', function handleSelectionChange(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log('item selected');
        })
    }]);
```

The tiles are displayed correctly as below. You may notice that the **Center** tile (tile with the blue border) that has been selected as a result of setting the **selection**. But any other **selection** still shows the same value - selecting any other item wont set the **selection**.

[image]

The libraries are below:

```
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/hammer.js/hammer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.44/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/winjs/4.4.0/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/winjs/4.4.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/winjs/4.4.0/js/ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/winjs/angular-winjs/master/js/angular-winjs.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/my-app.js"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `selection-mode="'single'" tap-behavior="'directSelect'"`

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['winjs']);
myApp.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', myCtrl]);

function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selection = [];
    $scope.homeTiles = [{
        title: 'A1'
    }, {
        title: 'A2'
    }, {
        title: 'A3'
    }, {
        title: 'A4'
    }, {
        title: 'A5'
    }, {
        title: 'A6'
    }];
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div>Selected count: {{selection.length}}, indexes: {{selection.toString()}}</div>
        <win-list-view item-data-source="homeTiles" selection="selection" selection-mode="'single'" tap-behavior="'directSelect'" class="listview win-selectionstylefilled">

            <win-item-template>This list view item's rating is: {{item.data.rating}}</win-item-template>
            <win-list-layout></win-list-layout>           
        </win-list-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working code [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shafeeq116/n74jpr0t/1/)

[WinJS ListView Interaction Examples](http://try.buildwinjs.com/playground/)  ( Choose from dropdown )